# Send Image Frames from C++ Server to C# Client using Named Pipe

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, ipc, named-pipes

I am noobie in `IPC`. I am trying to send the Image Frame from my `C++ Server` to `C# Client`. I have start learning about that and make a small `Client` and `Server` that In which my `C++ Server` sends `Hello`. I saw a related question and someone told to first convert the `Image` into `Byte Array` and then send that in same way as `Hello Message` but I am not able to do that.

**My Basic Client Server Code**

**C++ Code:**

```
    Mat image = imread("IMG_0_10_34_45_2018_1.bmp");
uchar buffer[500][500];
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
    {
        buffer[i][j] = image.at<unsigned char>(i, j);
    }
}
cout << "Server Creating Pipe\n";
HANDLE hPipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(_T("\\\\.\\pipe\\HyperPipe"),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
    4096,
    4096,
    0,
    NULL);

cout << "Server Created Succesfully";
ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);

cout << "Sending Message to Client";
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) * sizeof(uchar), &bytesWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hPipe);
return 0;
```

**And C# Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating Client Pipe");
    NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "HyperPipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
    Console.WriteLine("Pipe Created Successfully, Connecting to Server");
    pipe.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully, Connected to Server");
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(pipe, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Message from Server: " + rdr.ReadToEnd());
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I also noticed that in my `C++ Server` I have to change the `PIPE_TYPE to BYTE` and also `READMODE to BYTE`. I am using `OpenCV library` for `Image Processing` so I can easily make `Byte Array` no issue with that.

So, Can Anyone Please tell me how to send that `Byte Array` from `C++` to `C#`.
Or if possible that anyone can provide me the code for that

Thanks in Advance

**Update:**
No error is coming but at the client side i.e `C# Side` the the output of Message from Server is `?????`  .

Comment: Hmmm maybe use streams instead of messages since it is something somewhat large?

Comment: Yes Sir, I am using BYTE instead of MESSAGE but how to transfer the byte array?

Comment: No, I mean try `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` instead of `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`.  Sorry I should have been explicit

Comment: Yes I have done this

Comment: I am editing the C++ code What I done so far. At the Server side the message showing is ???.

Comment: No problem sir, I got the solution

Comment: Awesome!  Don't forget, if you found the solution yourself, feel free to post it as an answer below to your own question.  If a better answer doesn't come along you can **accept** it as the solution and thus get reputation points. Wishing you all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Send the Byte Array from `Server` to `Client` i.e the `buffer` just small changes in the `WriteFile` function is required.

```
WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) * sizeof(uchar), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

This method will send whole `Byte Array` to the `Client`
And also changing the `buffer`

```
int _count = 0;
UINT8 _imageBuffer[110592];
for (int _imageRow = 0; _imageRow < _image.rows; _imageRow++)
{
    for (int _imageCol = 0; _imageCol < _image.cols; _imageCol++)
    {
        buffer[_count] = image.at<uchar>(_imageRow, _imageCol);
        _count++;
    }
}
```

I have hardCode the buffer Array because I known that my camera will only send `110592` byte to create one frame.

And On the Client Side just use `Read` function.

```
            int _imageRowSize = 288;
            int _imageColSize = 384;
            int _count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[_imageColSize * _imageRowSize];
            Image<Gray, UInt16> image = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(_imageColSize,_imageRowSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Client Pipe");
            NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "HyperPipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
            Console.WriteLine("Pipe Created Successfully, Connecting to Server");
            pipe.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully, Connected to Server");
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    _count = 0;      
                    int read = pipe.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    for (int _imageRow = 0; _imageRow < 288; _imageRow++)
                    {
                        for (int _imageCol = 0; _imageCol < 384; _imageCol++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                image.Data[_imageRow, _imageCol, 0] = (UInt16)(buffer[_count] * 255);
                            }catch(Exception exception)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(exception);
                            }
                            _count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (read <= 0)
                        break;
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }           
            CvInvoke.Imshow("Image", image);
        }
```